# Using a hyperlink like a submit button

Tags: java, html, forms

in the past I used a submit-button to switch between several ftl sites (sorry if I use wrong terms here), with something like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="myServlet?action=showDetails&amp;kid=${mk.getM_name()}">
                            <input type="submit" id="details" value="${mk.getM_name()}"/>
```

Now i need to switch to something like a hyperlink where the Buttontext is now the text of the link and the result is the same like before.

How could I switch from a button to a hyperlink (in a form) with the same funcionility?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<c:url var="somepage" value="page">
    <c:param name="query" value="${stringSQLQuery}" />
</c:url>
<a href="${somepage}">link</a>
```

this how you can use , but if you want to make POST you can addEventListener to hyperlink and then add POST func here... hope useful ^^.